# Use Property in UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls, property-binding

I've made a usercontrol and added a new property like this:

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedBrushProperty;
    static MyControl() {
        SelectedBrushProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedBrush",
                                                            typeof(Brush),
                                                            typeof(MyControl),
                                                            new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.AliceBlue));
    }

    public Brush SelectedBrush {
        get {
            return (Brush)GetValue(SelectedBrushProperty);
        }
        set {
            SetValue(SelectedBrushProperty,value);
        }
    }
    public MyControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

My question is:
When in the XAML of my custom control, how can I use it?

Comment: `<local:MyControl SelectedBrush="White" />` .. not sure what you are after here.. Could you expand your question a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may bind to the property in the XAML of your Control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.MyControl" ...>
    <Grid>
        <Label Background="{Binding SelectedBrush,
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

If you set `DataContext = this;` in the constructor of MyControl, you may omit the `RelativeSource` of the binding:

```
<Label Background="{Binding SelectedBrush}"/>
```

---

Note that there is no need for the static constructor. You could write this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedBrushProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(MyControl),
                                new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.AliceBlue));
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Wow, I'm impressed that you picked that up from that question.. BTW, shouldn't the `AncestorType` be of `MyControl`, so that not any `UserControl` is found?

Comment: @Default The AncestorType could as well be `local:MyControl`, but that would require another XML namespace declaration like `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"`. Seems unnecessary to me, as there is no other UserControl in the ancestor hierarchy.